# Update one particular cell in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have table like this

```
Name      Answer
 A -------  Y
 B -------  N
 C  ------  N
 D  ------  Y
 E  ------  Y
```

and my problem is I want to update only cells which have 'Y', not updating whole answer column. What i have tried is

```
UPDATE TABLE1
        SET Answer = 'N' 
WHERE userID=1;
```

this update all the answers, I want to update only 'Y'

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you meant? You want to update all answers for 'User 1' where he has answered 'Y'?

`UPDATE TABLE1 SET Answer = 'N' WHERE userID=1 AND Answer = 'Y';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You can add filter on answer column on with your filter value.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET Answer = 'N' WHERE Answer = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET Answer = 'N' 
WHERE userID=1 
AND Answer = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..i''m not sure if this can be done without creating a new table...should be possible i guess

```
 select * into Table2 from Table1
 UPDATE TABLE2 SET Answer = case when userID=1 then 'N' else Answer end
 from table1 as a inner join table  table2 as b on a.name=b.name
```